# Rails Devise not keeping https on sign in/out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Running Rails 3.2.1 with devise-2.0.4.gem and devise_ldap_authenticatable-0.4.4.gem.

Everything is working fine with HTTP.  However, when deployed to production which uses HTTPS, after the user logged in, browser switches to HTTP which results in an error, since the production URL only supports HTTPS.  If I manually add a "s" back in the URL, then I can con't with the rails app. The app itself has not problems maintaining the HTTPS protocol.

Similar with sign-out in that the even though the sign-out link is HTTPS, clicking on the link will go to HTTP and fails.

Since the app can navigate around with HTTPS, it seems it's devise that's having trouble keeping the HTTPS protocol.  Any idea?  At this point, I don't even mind hard coding HTTPS for production.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Devise Wiki page about SSL? I think this might fix your problems: [How To: Use SSL (HTTPS)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29). All the steps to use HTTPS with devise are explained there.

If this is no help you should post your devise auth code here.

Comment: Now, I can see that Devise is redirecting to https, which is good.  But I'm getting this error on login:

== Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-03-23 10:29:08 -0700
== Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
== Redirected to https://MyCompany.com/users/sign_in
== Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x000000149d3028@/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb:28> rendered or redirected
== Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
== cache: [GET /users/sign_in] miss

Comment: could you add the error output and devise specific code to your question? you can format the output there, which is way more readable than in a comment. Also: which devise version are you using? Probably the latest devise version and the ldap-gem don't play nice with each other?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by setting the after_sign_in_path_for and after_sign_out_path_for in my application_controller.rb:

```
# Tell Devise to redirect after sign_in
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  'https://www.xyz.com/'
end

# Tell Devise to redirect after sign_out
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  'https://www.xyz.com/'
end
```